# Handshake exception occurring when connecting to SQL Server Azure with .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

So I opened up some code that hasn't been touched in about 2 months.

Last time I opened the application all unit tests passed. Now with no code changes all my data unit tests fail with the following error:

> Initialization method
>   PerTrac.Pictor.Data.Test.RequestLogRepositoryShould.CreateLog threw
>   exception. System.Data.EntityException: System.Data.EntityException:
>   The underlying provider failed on Open. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully
>   established with the server, but then an error occurred during the
>   pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait
>   operation timed out.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The
>   wait operation timed out.

I realize there is an existing question similar to this, but those solutions had no effect what so ever on my situation.

Has anyone experienced this error with entity framework and SQL Azure specifically ?

I should note that I can connect from SSMS with no issue using them same credentials. I don't have Force Encryption set on disabled protocols and I have reset my local IIS several times.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most likely you have some application installed on your computer that is using deprecated network protocols to intercept network traffic. The correct solution is hopefully to disable or uninstall those applications.

Run the command line command **netsh WinSock Show Catalog >> winsock.txt** and then **notepad winsock.txt** to open the file.

Look at every **Winsock Catalog Provider Entry** returned. If the **Service Flags** value has the 0x20000 bit set then the provider uses IFS handles and will work fine. If the “Service Flags” 0x20000 bit is clear (not set), then it is a non-IFS BSP or LSP and could be an issue. Try disabling this application and let us know if it then worked.

Ignore the “Name Space Provider Entry” when you are looking at the text file results. They aren't the problem.

Below is a sample of what my clean system looks like for the output of the netsh WinSock Show Catalog file.

```
Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider
Description:                        MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IP]
Provider ID:                        {E70F1AA0-AB8B-11CF-8CA3-00805F48A192}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1001
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     2
Max Address Length:                 16
Min Address Length:                 16
Socket Type:                        1
Protocol:                           6
Service Flags:                      0x20066
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider
Description:                        MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IP]
Provider ID:                        {E70F1AA0-AB8B-11CF-8CA3-00805F48A192}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1002
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     2
Max Address Length:                 16
Min Address Length:                 16
Socket Type:                        2
Protocol:                           17
Service Flags:                      0x20609
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider
Description:                        MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IP]
Provider ID:                        {E70F1AA0-AB8B-11CF-8CA3-00805F48A192}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1003
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     2
Max Address Length:                 16
Min Address Length:                 16
Socket Type:                        3
Protocol:                           0
Service Flags:                      0x20609
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider
Description:                        MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IPv6]
Provider ID:                        {F9EAB0C0-26D4-11D0-BBBF-00AA006C34E4}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1004
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     23
Max Address Length:                 28
Min Address Length:                 28
Socket Type:                        1
Protocol:                           6
Service Flags:                      0x20066
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider
Description:                        MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IPv6]
Provider ID:                        {F9EAB0C0-26D4-11D0-BBBF-00AA006C34E4}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1005
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     23
Max Address Length:                 28
Min Address Length:                 28
Socket Type:                        2
Protocol:                           17
Service Flags:                      0x20609
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider
Description:                        MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IPv6]
Provider ID:                        {F9EAB0C0-26D4-11D0-BBBF-00AA006C34E4}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1006
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     23
Max Address Length:                 28
Min Address Length:                 28
Socket Type:                        3
Protocol:                           0
Service Flags:                      0x20609
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider
Description:                        RSVP TCPv6 Service Provider
Provider ID:                        {9D60A9E0-337A-11D0-BD88-0000C082E69A}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1007
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     23
Max Address Length:                 28
Min Address Length:                 28
Socket Type:                        1
Protocol:                           6
Service Flags:                      0x22066
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider
Description:                        RSVP TCP Service Provider
Provider ID:                        {9D60A9E0-337A-11D0-BD88-0000C082E69A}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1008
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     2
Max Address Length:                 16
Min Address Length:                 16
Socket Type:                        1
Protocol:                           6
Service Flags:                      0x22066
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider
Description:                        RSVP UDPv6 Service Provider
Provider ID:                        {9D60A9E0-337A-11D0-BD88-0000C082E69A}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1009
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     23
Max Address Length:                 28
Min Address Length:                 28
Socket Type:                        2
Protocol:                           17
Service Flags:                      0x22609
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider
Description:                        RSVP UDP Service Provider
Provider ID:                        {9D60A9E0-337A-11D0-BD88-0000C082E69A}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1010
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     2
Max Address Length:                 16
Min Address Length:                 16
Socket Type:                        2
Protocol:                           17
Service Flags:                      0x22609
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider (32)
Description:                        MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IP]
Provider ID:                        {E70F1AA0-AB8B-11CF-8CA3-00805F48A192}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1001
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     2
Max Address Length:                 16
Min Address Length:                 16
Socket Type:                        1
Protocol:                           6
Service Flags:                      0x20066
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider (32)
Description:                        MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IP]
Provider ID:                        {E70F1AA0-AB8B-11CF-8CA3-00805F48A192}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1002
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     2
Max Address Length:                 16
Min Address Length:                 16
Socket Type:                        2
Protocol:                           17
Service Flags:                      0x20609
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider (32)
Description:                        MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IP]
Provider ID:                        {E70F1AA0-AB8B-11CF-8CA3-00805F48A192}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1003
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     2
Max Address Length:                 16
Min Address Length:                 16
Socket Type:                        3
Protocol:                           0
Service Flags:                      0x20609
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider (32)
Description:                        MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IPv6]
Provider ID:                        {F9EAB0C0-26D4-11D0-BBBF-00AA006C34E4}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1004
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     23
Max Address Length:                 28
Min Address Length:                 28
Socket Type:                        1
Protocol:                           6
Service Flags:                      0x20066
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider (32)
Description:                        MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IPv6]
Provider ID:                        {F9EAB0C0-26D4-11D0-BBBF-00AA006C34E4}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1005
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     23
Max Address Length:                 28
Min Address Length:                 28
Socket Type:                        2
Protocol:                           17
Service Flags:                      0x20609
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider (32)
Description:                        MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IPv6]
Provider ID:                        {F9EAB0C0-26D4-11D0-BBBF-00AA006C34E4}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1006
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     23
Max Address Length:                 28
Min Address Length:                 28
Socket Type:                        3
Protocol:                           0
Service Flags:                      0x20609
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider (32)
Description:                        RSVP TCPv6 Service Provider
Provider ID:                        {9D60A9E0-337A-11D0-BD88-0000C082E69A}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1007
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     23
Max Address Length:                 28
Min Address Length:                 28
Socket Type:                        1
Protocol:                           6
Service Flags:                      0x22066
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider (32)
Description:                        RSVP TCP Service Provider
Provider ID:                        {9D60A9E0-337A-11D0-BD88-0000C082E69A}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1008
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     2
Max Address Length:                 16
Min Address Length:                 16
Socket Type:                        1
Protocol:                           6
Service Flags:                      0x22066
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider (32)
Description:                        RSVP UDPv6 Service Provider
Provider ID:                        {9D60A9E0-337A-11D0-BD88-0000C082E69A}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1009
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     23
Max Address Length:                 28
Min Address Length:                 28
Socket Type:                        2
Protocol:                           17
Service Flags:                      0x22609
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Base Service Provider (32)
Description:                        RSVP UDP Service Provider
Provider ID:                        {9D60A9E0-337A-11D0-BD88-0000C082E69A}
Provider Path:                      %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1010
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     2
Max Address Length:                 16
Min Address Length:                 16
Socket Type:                        2
Protocol:                           17
Service Flags:                      0x22609
Protocol Chain Length:              1

Name Space Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        Network Location Awareness Legacy (NLAv1) Namespace
Provider ID:                        {6642243A-3BA8-4AA6-BAA5-2E0BD71FDD83}
Name Space:                         15
Active:                             1
Version:                            0


Name Space Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        E-mail Naming Shim Provider
Provider ID:                        {964ACBA2-B2BC-40EB-8C6A-A6DB40161CAE}
Name Space:                         37
Active:                             1
Version:                            0


Name Space Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        PNRP Cloud Namespace Provider
Provider ID:                        {03FE89CE-766D-4976-B9C1-BB9BC42C7B4D}
Name Space:                         39
Active:                             1
Version:                            0


Name Space Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        PNRP Name Namespace Provider
Provider ID:                        {03FE89CD-766D-4976-B9C1-BB9BC42C7B4D}
Name Space:                         38
Active:                             1
Version:                            0


Name Space Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        Tcpip
Provider ID:                        {22059D40-7E9E-11CF-AE5A-00AA00A7112B}
Name Space:                         12
Active:                             1
Version:                            0


Name Space Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        NTDS
Provider ID:                        {3B2637EE-E580-11CF-A555-00C04FD8D4AC}
Name Space:                         32
Active:                             1
Version:                            0


Name Space Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        WindowsLive NSP
Provider ID:                        {4177DDE9-6028-479E-B7B7-03591A63FF3A}
Name Space:                         12
Active:                             1
Version:                            1


Name Space Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        WindowsLive Local NSP
Provider ID:                        {229F2A2C-5F18-4A06-8F89-3A372170624D}
Name Space:                         19
Active:                             1
Version:                            1


Name Space Provider Entry (32)
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        Network Location Awareness Legacy (NLAv1) Namespace
Provider ID:                        {6642243A-3BA8-4AA6-BAA5-2E0BD71FDD83}
Name Space:                         15
Active:                             1
Version:                            0


Name Space Provider Entry (32)
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        E-mail Naming Shim Provider
Provider ID:                        {964ACBA2-B2BC-40EB-8C6A-A6DB40161CAE}
Name Space:                         37
Active:                             1
Version:                            0


Name Space Provider Entry (32)
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        PNRP Cloud Namespace Provider
Provider ID:                        {03FE89CE-766D-4976-B9C1-BB9BC42C7B4D}
Name Space:                         39
Active:                             1
Version:                            0


Name Space Provider Entry (32)
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        PNRP Name Namespace Provider
Provider ID:                        {03FE89CD-766D-4976-B9C1-BB9BC42C7B4D}
Name Space:                         38
Active:                             1
Version:                            0


Name Space Provider Entry (32)
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        Tcpip
Provider ID:                        {22059D40-7E9E-11CF-AE5A-00AA00A7112B}
Name Space:                         12
Active:                             1
Version:                            0


Name Space Provider Entry (32)
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        NTDS
Provider ID:                        {3B2637EE-E580-11CF-A555-00C04FD8D4AC}
Name Space:                         32
Active:                             1
Version:                            0


Name Space Provider Entry (32)
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        WindowsLive NSP
Provider ID:                        {4177DDE9-6028-479E-B7B7-03591A63FF3A}
Name Space:                         12
Active:                             1
Version:                            1


Name Space Provider Entry (32)
------------------------------------------------------
Description:                        WindowsLive Local NSP
Provider ID:                        {229F2A2C-5F18-4A06-8F89-3A372170624D}
Name Space:                         19
Active:                             1
Version:                            1
```

Comment: What do you mean by “Service Flags” 0x20000 bit is clear (not set)? What does it look like? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The key to understand the problem here is the provider and in your case it is "SSL Provider" and the main problem is that connection time out. If problem was related with "TCP Provider" there could be several reasons related with network etc however in your case it is a security related issue within the connection framework.

Next step to investigate this problem is that on the same machine, you can connect from SSMS to same SQL Database however not from IIS which means the IIS application process is not able to get proper certificate to create the SSL tunnel to create the successful connection. It is possible that you have some log written System Event log so please check there.

Because you are using Entity Framework and depend on EF version there are some changed in the connection string so verify if that is what you have:

```
<add name="MyDatabaseModelEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDBModel.csdl|res://*/MyDatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/MyDatabaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=abcdefg123.database.windows.net;initial catalog=MyDatabase;persist security info=True;user id=MyDatabaseUser@abcdefg123;password=p@$$w0rd;multipleactiveresultsets=True;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;App=EntityFramework"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Finally if you are using EF 4.3.1 and connecting to SQL Database please have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418671/Using-the-Entity-Framework-in-ASP-NET-MVC) article and check if you have similar configuration.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the security aspect. In my case, I was using LinqPad and I was getting this exception. Running the LinqPad instance as Administrator solved the problem. Just in case anybody else is experiencing the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

This issue is reported in microsoft connect site [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729323/visual-studio-11-beta-installation-disabled-my-abillity-to-connect-remote-ms-sql-server-but-not-local-databases#tabs). Solution is availabel [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2568167). You need to  remove non-IFS LSP installed Winsock Catalog Provider. Sometimes some software already installed on you machine may cause issue. In order to remove non-IFS LSP first run the following command on command prompt to see the application causing issue ([ref](http://www.herongyang.com/Windows/Winsock-netsh-winsock-show-catalog-LSP.html))

```
netsh winsock show catalog > LSP.txt
```

see the output and analyze the application causing issue and uninstall it. hopefully it will resolve the issue.

Comment: IIRC running this command gave me a huge list of command line information that was useless without further instruction. You are absolutely right this was exactly the problem, but running this command is useless if you don't know how to parse the information. This question is kind of popular for some reason. It would be great if you have more information about non-IFS LSP installed winsock catalog providers and how to go about using the information provided by the provided command.

Comment: just look the text file and see the installed programs and see the culprit

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after trying to repair my VS2012RC couple of times and no luck I chanced upon [this link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729323/visual-studio-11-beta-installation-disabled-my-abillity-to-connect-remote-ms-sql-server-but-not-local-databases), one of the comments is to do with a third party s/w called 'sendori'. I uninstalled it and all is back to normal in my world.

Answer (score 1):

Just another tip:
SQL server could be out of memory. I had this error and when I checked SQL server computer, the SQL service was using 15G of memory, out of 16 total. So restart the service to fix.

Comment: How big is the DB? SQL Server will typically consume as much memory as it can without causing adverse behaviour with the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being vs11 beta.

If you have this problem you need to do the following :

1) Uninstall vs11 beta and .NET 4.5 beta

2) re-install .NET 4.0

Watch everything work again !

Comment: This is not the right solution. This ignores the real issue with is some other application on the system not using correct protocols.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with SSMS 2012 but all worked fine on SSMS 2008 on the same box connecting to the same remote server.

Moca.io Proxy was causing trouble for me. Uninstalled and all working fine now. ("remove non-IFS LSP")

Answer (score 0):

had same problem.
In my case uninstalling T-Mobile Web 'n Walk Manager solved problem.
Its software for making mobile connection to internet via sim card
Josip

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error. Solved by setting server not to XXXXXXXXX but to the full domain name XXXXXXXX.YYY.com

Then a message appeared saying encryption was not supported connect without.

When I did everything worked.

Comment: Can you clarify the down vote I found this page by Googling my error. Error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dot "." or partial name of server (without domain name) for data source, please try with actual SQL Server instance name with complete server name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

- SQL Server on my local machine on ubuntu docker image

  - connecting via `localhost` port `1433`.
- Connect sucessfully to server from SQL Server Management Studio
- Unable to connect from application. Same exception as in OP:

`A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)`

After trying almost everything from [this port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999981/sql-azure-ssl-provider-error-0-the-wait-operation-timed-out), I have changed the database host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and it started working again.

Not sure if this exactly fixed the issue, but after this change it started working. But when I changed it back to `localhost` it still worked (no exception was thrown).