# .NET 4.5 and asynchronous Winsock with OVERLAPPED (non IFS Winsock BSPs or LSPs)

Tags: c#, .net

I was researching one of the issue I'm facing that similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082077/handshake-exception-occurring-when-connecting-to-sql-server-azure-with-net-4-5).   The issue basically resolves around a client application can't connect to the database.  The resolution seems to suggest that there is an application installed that not compatible with the network protocol and we should uninstall that application.

Based on my testing uninstall .NET 4.5 and loaded .NET 4.0 also does the trick and I want to find out why.  Upon researching more into I find the following:

.NET 4.5 has a change that make SQLClient supports asynchronous as per this [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx) ,

Due to this change, any application that uses asynchronous Winsock with OVERLAPPED structure with .NET 4.5 will cause the application not experience the completion of those Winsock call.

My reaction to this is, isn't this considered a .NET 4.5 bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might call it a Windows bug, but it's definitely not a .NET or SQL Server bug.

Winsock has two types of filter drivers: IFS and non-IFS. IFS drivers re-use Winsock functionality while non-IFS overrides it completely.

Prior to Windows Vista, async calls would both get a return value that indicates immediate success *and* get a completion notification. Vista added a perf-enhancing mode removes this redundant notification. IFS drivers got this for free, while non-IFS drivers now need to be updated to support it.

So you might call it a Windows bug by not maintaining backward compatibility to a deprecated API. It may have simply not been possible, and their new WFP architecture is made to replace it. I'd say it's closer to a driver bug -- you can't say you're compatible with Vista and then forget to implement one of the APIs.

Either way, it's a valid Windows feature and .NET/SQL is right to take full advantage of it for added perf. Per [KB2568167](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2568167), you can run this command to determine exactly what driver is causing the issue:

```
netsh WinSock Show Catalog
```

> If the Service Flags value has the 0x20000 bit set, the provider uses
>   IFS handles and will work correctly. If the 0x20000 bit is clear (not
>   set), it is a non-IFS BSP or LSP.

Comment: I totally understand and accepted your answer but I'm playing a devil's advocate here.   I came across this link https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729323/visual-studio-11-beta-installation-disabled-my-abillity-to-connect-remote-ms-sql-server-but-not-local-databases#tabs where Microsoft team lead also acknowledge they have a a bug, i guess this is a case where their own application violates the rule?

Comment: I don't see where they acknowledge they have a bug there. They are going to alert the vendor who is at fault.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a bug in .NET. The .NET Framework can assume that the underlying network infrastructure functions correctly. If there is a broken WinSock provider installed there is nothing that .NET can do in general to reach the database.

Neither is the .NET Framework responsible for working around bugs in 3rd-party installed software, nor is it possible to provide such behavior in general.